# How to remove Windows Theme's Styles?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been working with WPF for a couple of days now and I've pre-designed my project in photoshop. Now, I'm on my way to WPF development. The problem, however, is the following: Is there a way to block windows' themes? What I mean by that is that e.g. when creating a button it'll be styled the way I want it to be, but the hover/click events will still overwrite the design, which ultimately looks completely wicked. In a really bad way.
I guess, what I might be looking for is an equivalent to the wildcard accessible in css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you problems so if you want to make a complete customize button according to you then you can use `Template` property of button.

You can write some style code in windows resources section.

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.ButtonTemplating"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ButtonTemplating" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#373737" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />

                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E59400" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />

                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Button Width="200" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">WPF</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override any of the windows themes by applying your own control templates. The hover/click events are part of these templates.

If you make the control templates part of a resource, you can then reuse them across all your controls.

The default templates can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.110).aspx

Button styles and templates can be found here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx